# Specific pattern to match and extract info from string

Tags: javascript, regex, node.js, extract

I need to be able identifying over a string if it matches with the following patterns:

':module-name' || 'com.example.ClassName' || ':module-name:com.example.ClassName' || 'http://url';

I need to identify if the string matches one of the above patterns, lets split them into 3 groups (urls, local & none) where a url stands for a valid url string. In the other hand local must be in 3 different variants (':module-name' || 'com.example.ClassName' || ':module-name:com.example.ClassName') if this is the case I need to extract the module and component names.

The module name must be a valid nodejs package name and the component name must be a valid Class name (I got the valid class name already covered with this RegExp: /^@?[a-z_A-Z]\w+(?:.@?[a-z_A-Z]\w+)*$/).

What I need is a way to identify where the string belongs to one of the groups (url, local or none) and in case of local, extract the module and component name. The best for a regular expression solution...

Thanks

Comment: What are the module name and component name portions of example string?

Comment: They are strings too, one represents a valid nodejs package name (module-name) and the other one is a string which must be a valid java kind package name, I've covered this verification but I need a regex which allow me identify and extract the parts within the string ":package:component-name" or ":package" or "component-name", those are the variants I'm attempted to check.

Comment: You are trying to match portion of string beginning with `":"`?

Comment: Yes my friend, I need to match the string over one of the above variants and extract the values package-name and the other value from the string, beginning with ":" or not and with it in the middle or not as shown above

Comment: What is `":module-name"` followed by in string?

Comment: Can or not be followed by ":component-name", yes its a string

Comment: `":module-name:com.example.ClassName"match(/[:][a-z.]+/ig)`

Comment: i've tested and it does extract the matches but if I change the string a bit like "1232&%:module-name:com.example.ClassName" it also passes the function, I need it just beging with ":". Anyways this is going in the right way...

Comment: `/^([:][a-z.]+)/ig`

Comment: Only return :module, in case of module-name which is a valid nodejs package name, it removes the whole "-name" part!!

Comment: _"I need it just beging with ":""_?

Comment: the string must bigin with ":" (followed by a valid npm package name) then ":" (valid java kind package name) at the end

Comment: What is pattern for valid npm package name?

Comment: This is the closest thing I've found related to that: https://github.com/npm/validate-npm-package-name

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By using the amazing web tool referenced by Croutonix I was able to produce the RegExp and test it real time:

The solution is /^:([a-z][a-z_-]*)+:{0,1}([a-z_A-Z]\w+(?:.?[a-z_A-Z]\w+)*)$/gm.exec(string)

Answer (score 1):

Can this work? [See on regex101](https://regex101.com/r/KBG6W4/3)

```
^:.+-.+:.+\..+\..+|^:.+-.+|^.+\..+\..+|^http[s]?:\/\/.+
```

It matches `:x-x`, `x.x.x`, `:x-x:x.x.x`, `http[s]://x`, x being any character repeated between 1 and unlimited times. It won't match any of those if preceded by something. But it will match `com.class.class.class.class` and `http://invalidUrl`. As you said you check if class name is good. If you want only valid url, then you can replace `^http[s]?:\/\/.+` with `https?:\/\/(\w+:{0,1}\w*@)?(\S+)(:[0-9]+)?(\/|\/([\w#!:.?+=&%@!\-\/]))?` or any regex validating urls. (I did not invent this one)